# In ADTF 3, how can we create a drop-down list for the filter properties?

Tags: adtf, adtf3

In ADTF 2 we could do that using NSSUBPROP. I am looking for a similar function in ADTF3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still possible but you have to differ between the two concepts of the major version. In ADTF 3.x the configuration is encoupled from runtime, this means ADTF Configuration Editor will not load .adtfplugins, it will load .plugindescriptions, which can be generated from the plugin itself and merged with custom information. For runtime it is only necessary which type of property and which value is set. For CE, there can be comboboxes, this must be done manually in .plugindescription and merged with the generated one if necessary. There is an example missing (coming) but to do so have a look here:

```
<property_set_description>
        <property_descriptions>          
          <property_description>
            <name>operation</name>
            <type>tInt</type>
            <value>0</value>
            <list>
                <property_list_enumeration>
                    <name>Add</name>
                    <value>0</value>
                </property_list_enumeration>
                <property_list_enumeration>
                    <name>Subtract</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property_list_enumeration>
                <property_list_enumeration>
                    <name>Multiply</name>
                    <value>2</value>
                </property_list_enumeration>
                <property_list_enumeration>
                    <name>Divide</name>
                    <value>3</value>
                </property_list_enumeration>
            </list>
            <list_extendable>false</list_extendable>
          </property_description>

          ...
```

Please have a look at the stylesheet -> https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/adtf_html/page_adtfxsd_plugindescription.html

There will also be a UI Support (Plugin Description Editor) in upcoming versions.

Comment: Hey @C-3PFLO.
Thanks a lot for your answer.